# How to use RCPTT Folder Context in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, eclipse-rcptt

Let me know about how to mavinize  *Folder Context* in RCPTT!

FYI: I have created a folder context (`my_folder_context.ctx` referring to a remote folder). First I click "Apply" button after opening the `.ctx` file in RCPTT tool to copy the contents to AUT location than execute the test cases to get the test data.

But while automating the same I don't find any entry for `*.ctx` file in [RCPTT-maven-plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/rcptt/documentation/userguide/maven/). For suites we have below:

```
 <suites>
  <suite>MyTestSuite</suite>
</suites>
```

...but the same I didn't find for `*.ctx` files or any way to refer the folder context from ECL script .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the short answer is this is NOT possible as the foldercontext is obviously not a testcase. You can only add the test case inside test suit.And it does not make any sense to execute a foldercontext file which is not doing any thing and no result or report can be generated out of it.

By the  way let me share few of my learning here:

1)Folder context can be used while recording time in rcptt but runtime it's of no use. Basically it's like a mapped directory for a remote location available inside your rcptt tool.

2)I had provided the test data location at runtime and the same I achieved through below:
Go to RCPTT->Run configurations ->VM Arguments append -D"testdatalocation" (without double quote) and provide below
in ECL script :

```
set-dialog-result Folder [substitute-variables "${system_property:testdatalocation}"]
```

or in your maven pom.xml file :

```
<vmArgs>
      <vmArg>-Dtestdatalocation=D:\InputsForAutomation</vmArg>
</vmArgs>
```